# LINQ statement issue after .NET Core 8.0 update

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-8.0

My project was on .NET Core 3.1 and I updated the version into .NET  8.0 and also updated the Entity Framework version. Now I am getting this issue while retrieving data from database using LINQ. But other LINQ statements are working without any issue.

```
return context.TransactionEvents 
              .Where(x => transList.Contains(x.TransactionId)
                          && x.EventId == 30);
```

This was my project file details when it was on .NET 3.1:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</

IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This is my project file details after updation to .NET 8.0:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.1.38" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
> at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)     at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()

Comment: Could you please add the definition and configuration of relevant entities?

Comment: Also the question is tagged both EF6 and EF Core. Those are two different things. Could you please clarify? The exception trace is from EF Core but it is unclear which framework you used with .net core 3.1

Comment: I got the issue in .NET core 8.0. I was used .NET 3.1, got the issue after the updation.
Here is the package details : https://ibb.co/WFCLMbS

Comment: That project containe both EF and EF Core as well as ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core. I don't know whether this is intentional but troubleshooting any kind of issues in such a project will probably be quite complicated. Please edit the project file definition as a code into your question. As well as the relevant entities as requested prior. Providing a minimal repro would be the best way forward, though.

Comment: I got the issue in .NET core 8.0. I was used .NET 3.1, got the issue after the updation. Here is the package details in .NET 8.0 : https://ibb.co/WFCLMbS 
And This was my package details when the project was in .NET 3.1 : https://ibb.co/dQqCN9T

Comment: Please edit these definitions into the question, providing links with screenshots is prone to link rot and cannot be easily copied as it is not text.

Comment: Looks like there is a breaking change in EFCore 8, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#sqlserver-contains-compatibility . Please check the link and follow the mitigation method.

Comment: What's your sql server version/compatibility mode? Does it support OPENJSON?

Comment: When you get a `SqlException` the first thing to check is the SQL that is executed. It's an indispensable part of the debugging skillset when working with EF.